# Deserialization of interfaces using Jackson, where the interface implementation is specified in the serialized object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following sort of structure (simplified to hopefully make the problem clearer):

```
interface Settings {
    ...
}

interface Component {
    ...
}

class Container {
    Class<? extends Component> component;
    Settings settings;
}

@SettingsClass(MySettings.class)
class MyComponent implements Component{
    ...
}

class MySettings implements Settings{
    ...
}
```

If I serialize an instance of `Container` using Jackson, I get a JSON that looks a bit like:

```
{
    component: "my.package.MyComponent"
    settings: { ... }
}
```

This is exactly what I want.

But I can't deserialize that JSON because Jackson doesn't know which implementation of Settings to use. At run time, I can retrieve the SettingsClass annotation and identify which class the `settings` field should be deserialized to.

Is there a way for me to get Jackson to partially deserialize the JSON, and then have it deserialize the rest (i.e. the `settings`) once I've been able to inspect the `component` and determine which `Settings` class to use?

Comment: You might want `@JsonTypeInfo`, which you seem to be duplicating with your `component` property. Also note that I always recommend using a type alias (usually with the property name `@type`) so that future upgrades to your application internals don't break serialization.

Comment: Thanks - I can't modify the classes directly as they're in a different library, but I have now added type information with a MixIn. It doesn't duplicate the component property as the settings class is a different class.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. I had to do something similar recently. I parsed into JsonNode and checked the property manually.

```
final JsonNode jsonRoot = new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonString);
//...
Optional.ofNullable(jsonRoot.get("component")).map(JsonNode::textValue) ...
```

Then serialized the tree into the POJO.

```
new ObjectMapper().readerFor(theClass).readValue(jsonRoot)
```

Not amazing, but saves parsing the entire string twice at least.

Comment: Thanks - I'm hoping to avoid parsing myself, so have modified my JSON to include the type information.